# What exactly is HttpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition?

Tags: c#

Can I store values like the version number of a file in HttpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition?

I need to write the version number of a file in the headers or somewhere else because I want to find out if the client has stored the newest version of a certain file on his iOS/Android smart phone.

For example: Today, the client downloads the very first time a file named MyFile.txt from a server. Tomorrow, the client needs to check if there is a new version of MyFile.txt on the server. If yes, download it. If no, don't download it.

Where can I store the version number of a text file so that the client can find out if the file on the server is newer than the stored version?

Is it possible to store it in HttpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition or is it necessary that I always create a new file and file name, for example MyFileVersion1.txt, MyFileVersion2.txt, ...?

This is how I download a file. I use new ContentDisposition(httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.ToString()).FileName to get the file name.

```
string DownloadFile = await DownloadFileAsync(URL);

async Task<string> DownloadFileAsync(string fileUrl)
{
var _httpClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15) };

try
{
    using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(fileUrl))
    {
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string localfilename = new ContentDisposition(httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.ToString()).FileName;
            byte[] byteresponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            string documentsPathnew = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            string localPathnew = Path.Combine(documentsPathnew, localfilename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(localPathnew, byteresponse);
            return "Saved file: " + localfilename;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Url is invalid";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return "Exception. Something went wrong.";
}
}
```

Comment: Don't try to repurpose standard HTTP headers, they are standard for a reason. If you need your own special header, add it.

Comment: How can I add my own special header? I don't want that the client needs to download a text file to get/read its version number. I want to get the version number of a text file without downloading the file from the server. I just want to download the file if its version number is newer.

Comment: Then you should use an HTTP HEAD request, which will give you all the headers of the file without actually downloading it. As for versioning, there is already a standard HTTP header called ETag that returns a hash of the resource being downloaded - client apps should check that header and only attempt to download the resource if its ETag differs to what the client has.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) states that

> The Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user requests that the content is saved to a file.

Why not just use a [`NameValueHeaderValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.namevalueheadervalue?view=netframework-4.8) with a name of `Version` and a value of whatever you want?

Comment: How can I add NameValueHeaderValue with a name of "Version" and a value of "1" to my text file when I upload the file to an url? How can the client read NameValueHeaderValue when it is checking other text files for a newer version? The client needs to find out if the text files on the server have a newer version than the file that is stored on the device.